# how many key value pairs be emitted with m mapper and r reducers and k unique words for a wordcount program?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

This seems to be a question that i am finding on internet. According to me answer should be exactly k/r and not approximately k/r? what's your take? I know it will be r files as output.

```
If you run the word count MapReduce program with m mappers and r reducers, how many output files will you get at the end of the job? And how many key-value pairs will there be in each file? Assume k is the number of unique words in the input files.
A. There will be r files, each with exactly k/r key-value pairs.
B. There will be r files, each with approximately k/m key-value pairs.
C. There will be r files, each with approximately k/r key-value pairs.
D.There will be m files, each with exactly k/m key value pairs.
E.There will be m files, each with approximately k/m key-value pairs.
```

Answer (score 2):

Option C is correct.

Number of output files produced by mapreduce job will be equal to number of reducers executed. So, `there will be r files created`.

By default mapreduce framework used HashPartition to partition the key.

```
Partition = (Hash value of the key) % (Number of reducers)
```

So, if two or more keys has same hash values, then it will go to the same partition. In this scenario we cannot expect exactly k/r key-value pairs.

We can get exactly k/r key-values if and only if hash value for all the keys are different.

So, the final answer will be `each with approximately k/r key-value pairs.`